# How can I avoid shooting my lips?

Tags: archery

For the first few arrows I often have the problem, that the string rubs over my lips. I need to concentrate on turning the face more to the target.

However, these few arrows are sometimes that harsh, that they leave me with a bloody lip.

Is there anything I can do to remember to turn my head at the first go-off? Something less painful than a bloody lip please =)

Trivia:

- Best thing would be to break the habit completely of course
- A reminder (like a note or something) wouldn't work, cause I forget about it while I actively shoot (even if I walk to the court with a "turn your head"-consideration)

Comment: are you trying to "aim" with one eye?

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Nope, both eyes open for intuitive shooting.

Comment: What are your knock points made of?

Comment: and your draw length is correct?

Comment: @Dynadin It's made out of brass (plastic inside)

Comment: @ErikvanDoren What do you mean with "correct"? =) It's like it is 29,5" :D

Comment: @OddDeer correct for you, everybody has their own and a small difference often involves a change of posture, one of this changes is a possible turning of the head. If it happens to you at the beginning it could be that after a few shots the body compensates for it in other ways and you start changing head position then. If you have a buddy that can look at your posture and correct it it would help, if its someone that wouldnt know what to look for, have them taking pictures square from the side and behind so you can check yourself. Its worth checking, you never know.

Comment: PS: if you want to take selfshots because you are alone dont use pics on a timer. Put the camera on movie recording and keep recording. Often at first the posture is better because you know pics are been taken, it changes once you get more relaxed. On flat ground small problems with posture might not matter much for the shot but it would start being an issue once you are down/uphill etc. So it wouldnt be time wasted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [kisser button](https://archerycoach.wordpress.com/tag/kisser-buttons/), perhaps? They are a button on your string designed specifically to help orient your head.

Comment: AFAIK, a kisser button would only work if he was shooting Olympic style (drawing with his hand underneath his chin). I assume as he is shooting barebow (anchoring at the corner of his mouth) as he's intuitive shooting.

Answer (score 4):

There is a possibility that your lips are catching on your knock points. It can take a few arrows to get your form at the start of a day.

I used to have brass knock points as well. After a while I replaced them with string floss (the one used for teeth) sealed with glue. It eliminated the problem for me.